# Session expires in laravel and log the user out, after submitting forms

Tags: php, laravel, forms, session, laravel-5

I am developing an application in PHP. When I submit a form Laravel expires the session and then logs the user out.

My view

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype'=> 'multipart/form-data', 'class'=>'', 'data-smk-icon'=>"fas fa-exclamation"])!!}
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titulo" class="label-input100">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" class="i form-control">
        </div> @csrf

        <button type="submit"> Publish</button>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

My controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{  
    $post = Post::find(2);
    return 'Details:' . $post;
}
```

My Routes

```
Route::resource('/artigos','PostsController');
```

I had to restart the whole project due to this error, but still it persists.

Comment: What middlewares do you have?

Comment: Where have you defined these routes?

Comment: @Jerodev In web.php.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte. I have the authenticate. CheckForManteinance, EncryptCookies, Direct if Authenticated, TrimStrings, TrustProxies and VerifyCsrfToken

Comment: It's hard to know. Look at your middlewares and check which one handle the session/Auth. Probably one of them is loggin user out

Comment: The most weird thing is: this happens randomly, a fun fact is when i was shoeing this a fellow programmer, this wasn't happening. 5 mins later again, and i haven't touched any of the code. Ive checked them , I didnt change any of them